# Generating routes in javascript with Twig and Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, routes, twig

Quite odd problem, sorry for asking, i'm quite new to Symfony/Twig. My route requires a mandatory `region_id` paramenter:

```
ajax_provinces_by_region:
  pattern: /ajax/region/{region_id}/provinces
  defaults: {_controller: SWAItaliaInCifreBundle:Ajax:provincesByRegion }
  requirements: {region_in: \d+}
```

The **question** is: how can i generate this route based on a `select` element in javascript (code below)?

The **problem** is: i can't use `path` and `url` helpers from Symfony as they require to specify the `region_id` parameter (`this.value`) i can't access because it's a javascript variable (and Twig is compiled server-side).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#regions').change(function(){

        // Make an ajax call to get all region provinces
        $.ajax({
            url: // Generate the route using Twig helper
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: you can use this trick if you don't like to use bundle : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16584335/4008043

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: Routing.generate('route_name')

Answer (score 79):

I know it's an old question, but just in case you don't want to install a bundle like FOSJsRoutingBundle, here's a little hack:

```
var url = '{{ path("yourroute", {'region_id': 'region_id'}) }}'; 
url = url.replace("region_id", this.value);
```

'region_id' is just used as a placeholder, then you replace it in JS with your actual variable this.value

Comment: This is a good variant, but FOSJsRoutingBundle the best solution.

Comment: This will escape '&' characters inside url to &amp;

Comment: This will not work is my js file is inside asset folder, which is sibling of src folder..

Comment: I thought this was the best solution and I've been using it successfully for a while. Where it fails is if you have routing requirements and multiple values. For example I had a route with two variables and both must be digits (`"\d+"`) so for temporary values I was adding a simple integer into the each one then replacing. What eventually caught me is that the id of the real item got replaced on the 2nd url.replace causing an invalid path to be generated.

Answer (score 4):

```
url:  "{{ path('SampleBundle_route',{'parameter':controller_value}) }}"
```

Where `SampleBundle_route` is a valid path defined in routing.yml or annotatins.

For testing, write this in the twig template:

```
<script>
    var url= "{{ path('SampleBundle_route') }}";
    alert(url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="event_edit", options={"expose"=true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute in your HTML:

```html
<select id="regions">
    {% for region in regions %}
        <option data-path="{{ path('ajax_provinces_by_region', {'region_id': region.id}) }}">...</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

then in your javascript:

```
$('select#regions').on('change', function() {

    let path = $(this).find(':selected').data('path')

    $.ajax({
        'url': path
    })
})
```