# passing more than one javascript parameter to a PHP file with twig

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I want to pass three parameter to a PHP file with twig `path()`.  I found a solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009271/using-javascript-variable-in-twig-template-using-silex-framework).
It works fine with one value, but with two values it puts `&amp;` instead of `&` in the URL. this is the code I used:

```
var route = "{{ path('dashboardTable', { 'data1': 'fistData', 'data2' : 'secondData})}}";
route = route.replace('firstData',  D1);
route = route.replace('secondData',  D2 );
window.location.href = route;
```

It sets the `firstData` and `socondData` and the URL will be this:

`http://localhost:8000/dashboard/table?data1=Low&amp;data2=deactive`

but because of the `&amp;` it's not working. 
how can I change `&amp;` to `&` ?

the funny point is that if I put the `amp;` before `data2` in my get request like below, it works fine!

```
$data2 = $_GET["amp;data2];
```

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633676/symfony2-twig-stop-escaping-path.

Comment: Have you tried applying the `raw` filter as per - http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/escaping.html

Comment: @DaveCoast it worked. thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to DaveCoast comment I added `raw` in the code like below and it solved the problem .

```
var route = "{{ path('dashboardTable', { 'data1': 'fistData', 'data2' : 'secondData})|raw}}";
route = route.replace('firstData',  D1);
route = route.replace('secondData',  D2 );
window.location.href = route;
```