# variable jquery inside twig template

Tags: jquery, variables, twig

I'm trying to use a jquery varaible inside a twig template to send by ajax, but I can't access to the jquery variable  inside the twig:

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){


                jQuery("#my_input").change(function(){

                    var value = jQuery("#my_input").val();

                    jQuery.ajax({

                        url: "{{ path('ParteAccidentes_ajax', {'emergencia': value}) }}",
                        timeout: 5000,
                        success: function(data) { 
                           alert('ok');
                        },
                        error: function() { 
                            alert('mal');
                        }
                    });

                });

            });  
        </script>
```

The error show is variable value doesn't exist (in "url:..." line)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that Twig is launched before than JavaScript and the variable "id_emergencia" is not recognized by Twig. You could do a trick. You can put a string, as a parameter and then, in the JavaScript code, you replace the string with the value of your variable. In this way, you will always have the correct url before your AJAX petition is launched.

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                jQuery("#my_input").change(function(){
                    
                    var value = jQuery("#my_input").val();
                    var url = "{{ path('ParteAccidentes_ajax', {'emergencia': 'text'}) }}";
                    url = url.replace("text", value);
                                        
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        
                        url: url,
                        timeout: 5000,
                        success: function(data) { 
                           alert ('ok');
                        },
                        error: function() { alert ('mal');
                        }
                    });

                });

            });  
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does not exist.

The `value` variable is just plain text for Twig. Remember:

First the Twig parts are rendered, then it gets outputted to the browser, then the Browser renders the content and executes the Javascript.

The line `{{ path('ParteAccidentes_ajax', {'emergencia': value}) }}` is executed way before `value` is event parsed as javascript.

Also you're doing this in an event handler.

How should twig (since it's just a PHP library) change the path url on a executed javascript event?

Since you just want to update an URL based on symfony paths and a javascript variable, please have a look at this bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

It provides the exact functionality you want.

Comment: using another bundle just for getting the route seems like an overkill. The simple [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) solution seems better on the performance aspect. Although good to know that theres a bundle just for this! :)