# How to generate Symfony 2 twig URL with parameter value from Javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I want to append query string parameters from javascript (jquery) to symfony 2 url. 
I want to pass the value of selected radio button to ajax request e.g.in plain php I would have done like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.id_radio').click(function() {                      
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'example.php?id='+($this).val(),
            'success': function(r) {
                $('#div1').html(r);
            }
        });
    });
```

How to generate such URL in symfony2 twig ? We generate URL in symfony 2 twig like

`{{ path('example_path', {'id': id}) }}` where id is twig variable.

I tried using FOSJsRoutingBundle but don't know if it is for same problem and not sure how to use it ?

I tried below but it is not working.

```
$('.id_radio').click(function() {
    alert(Routing.generate('example_path', {
        'id': $(this).val()
        }));
    $.ajax({
        'url': Routing.generate('example_path', {
            'id': $(this).val()
            }),
        'success': function(r) {
            $('#div1').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

Solution mentioned below by koskoz worked, I did not pass options={"expose"=true} but after adding it worked.

But there is one more problem. It works only until we do not refresh page. If we refresh page, it does not work. To make it work, I have to delete symfony cache files.

It does not work in other browser if we have already opened it in one browser.

Comment: i found the solution here thanks to Airam :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16584335/4008043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
/**
 * @Route("/example/{name}", name="example_path", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Template
 */
public function exampleAction($name)
{

}
```

and using FOSJsRoutingBundle

```
$('.id_radio').click(function() {
    alert(Routing.generate('example_path', {'id': $(this).val()}));
    $.ajax({
        'url': Routing.generate('example_path', {'id': $(this).val()}),
        'success': function(r) {
            $('#div1').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

Below worked better for me,

```
     /**
     * @Route("/example", name="example_path", options={"expose"=true})
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template 
     */
    public function exampleAction()
    {


    }

$('.id_radio').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': '{{ path('example_path') }}',
        'data': 'name='+$(this).val(),
        'type': 'GET',
        'success': function(r) {
            $('#div1').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works because you're adding your JavaScript directly inside your Twig's templates, but the `path` helper won't work inside a .js file. You may have a caching issue with assetic, because I used the FOSJsRoutingBundle a lot of times as told in the doc and I've faced your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) is aiming for:

You configure the route you want to expose in JavaScript, load the JS and then simply do something like this :

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });
```

Comment: there is one more problem. It works only until we do not refresh page. If we refresh page, it does not work. To make it work, I have to delete symfony cache files.

It does not work in other browser if we have already opened it in one browser.

Answer (score 1):

Get the fosjsrouting bundle from here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle
and in your routing file add for that route

options: 
    expose: true

And in your js file add
    url = Routing.generate('route_name', {parameter: parameter_value});